# how to login a tty at startup

Tags: command-line, login, tty

I want to execute some command on special tty (for example tty2) in my Linux startup so every time the system reboots this commands execute on that tty. 
I used [this](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/) link to do so.

It works fine but problem is, in startup I need to login desired tty then execute the commands. Is there any way to login a tty by some command at the beginning? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution to running a program, IMHO would be to combine the `--autologin` flag of `getty` and a function that runs your desired commands from `.bashrc` .

**Part 1: autologin to getty**

As you may or may not know, TTYs are opened with a [getty program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_%28Unix%29) as a startup service in `/etc/init/` directory. For Ubuntu, default program is `agetty`, which has `--autologin` flag. Thus, we can do the following:

In terminal run `sudo nano /etc/init/tty1.conf` to open init file for TTY1 (notice that TTY1 is just an example, could be whichever you choose) . Change line

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

to

```
exec /sbin/getty --autologin userName    -8 38400 tty1
```

Replace  `userName` with your actual userName.

**Part 2: running a function on shell login**

Linux/Unix systems have this nice little program called `tty` that reports what kind of terminal you are using at the moment. For instance, in gnome-terminal it would report something like

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/27
```

In TTY1 however it would report

```
$ tty
/dev/tty1
```

Knowing that we can create a function at the top of our `$HOME/.bashrc` file

```
function testTTY
{
  isTTY=$(tty | awk '{if ($0~/\/dev\/tty.*/) {print "true"}else{print "false"}}')

  if [ $isTTY == "true" ]; then
    printf "You are in virtual console\n"
    printf "current disk usage is"
    df
  fi
}
```

Then at the bottom of the `.bashrc` make a call to your function, simply as `testTTY`. So, define function first, call it later.

**Side notes:**

- place custom commands between the `if [];then ...fi`
- If you need specific TTY change `isTTY` code to this: `isTTY=$(tty | awk '{if ($0=="/dev/tty1") {print "true"}else{print "false"}}')`

Answer (score 2):

follow the below steps.

First install mingetty:
$ sudo apt-get install mingetty

5.2)    Edit /etc/init/tty1.conf

/* For making Root as default Login */

Change: exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1

To: exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin root --noclear tty1

/* For making a normal user as default login */

exec /bin/login -f abcuser < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1